# Xamarin forms. Coletar frames da câmera

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

Saudações a todos!

Surgiu a necessidade de desenvolver um aplicativo onde a minha maior dificuldade nesse momento é carregar a câmera do celular em um objeto e de alguma forma obter algum evento onFrameChange da câmera.

Pretendo criar uma interface em um tablet em modo paisagem onde, do lado direito terei um teclado numérico e do lado esquerdo terei a câmera (frontal) carregada.

Esses frames da câmera posteriormente serão enviados à um servidor via WebAPI ou Websocket.

Sobre o layout e outros recursos, sem problema, mas carregar a câmera e interceptar cada frame é algo que eu não tenho a menor ideia de como implementar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa questão?

Comment: Para ler a câmera do celular você teria que criar um aplicativo para o celular cujo enviasse os frames da câmera em bytes através do localhost. Em .NET nativo você consegue emular somente a câmera do computador.